# Discord / Python: How to get user roles within a def (function)

Tags: python, roles, discord

I would like to check for the roles of users which are part of a textfield in a database (sqlite3).
My problem is that I can't use message.author or messege.mentions to get the user-"variable".
So what I have is the Name and the discriminator of that user. I could possibly also get the userid if that would help for my problem.

Now with those data I want to check if the user has a specific role (or which role) he has. But since my database only returns plain text (I hope I describe it correctly) it seems I can't use it this way:
user = "Someone#123" 
print (user.roles)

Is there a way to do what I want?
How can I get the "user" to be set correct so that I can further process with the roles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more information about where you're getting data from, what the exact layout of the data is and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'm getting the data out of a sylite3 database. The Format is like I already described. For Example
":Username1#1234:Username2#666:Username3#0815"
For the 3 Users:
Username1 with Discriminator 1234  
Username2 with Discriminator 666  
Username3 with Discriminator 0815  
 (Sorry I don't get how to force carriage returns or code here)
The data are entered by the Bot itself when people request them to store their infos in. 
I considered querying the roles at that point but I have a different problem with that in this case so I tried to avoid it and query the roles later...